# iOS Safari not triggering 'rotate' event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari

I've been trying various method to trigger an event when I rotate the device. It works on all browsers Android. It works on all browsers on iOS, except for Safari. I have tried 1 iPhone and 2 iPads, all on iOS7, and just can't get this event to fire.

I have tried:

jquery:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {

$(window).bind("resize", function(){


js:

document.addEventListener("orientationchange", updateOrientation);

window.onresize = function(event) {
```

No luck, no luck whatsoever. They all work in all browsers, but fail in iOS Safari. What's weirdest, is that sometimes it will fire maybe once or twice, in 20 rotations. Other times, no event at all. What is going on? Anyone have any experience with this? Am I doing something wrong, or is it a weird bug?

Answer (score 2):

Boy, orientChange type support is super dodgy across mobile browsers it seems. So, to avoid worrying about it, I just followed this simple guaranteed approach that doesn't rely on that event at all:

```
function findOrientation()
{
    if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
        return 'portrait';
    } else {
        return 'landscape';
    }
}

function checkOrientation() {   //to be run every X seconds by setInterval below
    var currentPortraitOrLandscape = findOrientation();
    if(currentLandscapeOrPortrait != window.landscapeOrPortrait) {
         doMyOrientationChangeCode();
         }
    }

window.portraitOrLandscape = findOrientation();

setInterval(checkOrientation, 800);  //check around once a second if they have reoriented
```